# What is the most suitable data type for multiple properties (keys) and a list as a value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, types, windows-phone

I need a somehow 'complicated' data type to store my data:

- **3 properties: angle, width, height**
- A big list with up to 4000 items which I want to **categorize to groups** with values higher/lower/equal each of these 3 properties.
- I need a data type to store each combination of these three properties a (sub-)list of items that fit in these three categories.
- **Edit:** There is also one special case where the property height can have all values (e.g. 100-200, 200-300, 300-400; but also 100-400).
- This data type should be very **fast** & support the possibility to get the (sub-)list of items when specifying the values of the three properties.

I imagine something like the following:

`dataType[angle][width][height] --> returns a list with items exactly fitting to these three categories`

It is like a **key-value-pair but with three keys and the value is the (sub-)list**.

I am now unsure what the best (and most performant) dataType for the implementation in C# (for WindowsPhone) is:
 - I could easily do it with an ObservableCollection and Linq-Queries. But it will be slow and maybe overkill
 - I think an internal database might be overkill too, especially as I think the one on WindowsPhone is a bit slow...
 - Is there something else I missed (Dictionary, Hash, etc.)?

Any suggestions is really much appreciated! (And I hope, I could describe my problem understandable...)

Comment: A dictionary using a Tuple<x,y,z> as key and your List as value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a class to hold onto the three pieces of data that you have, and so long as we give that type sensible `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations we can use it as the key in a `Dictionary`, which is a hash based structure with very fast lookup speeds.

```
public class Foo : IEquatable<Foo> //TODO give better name
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Foo);
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return Angle == other.Angle &&
            Width == other.Width &&
            Height == other.Height;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { Angle, Width, Height }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

(You could also modify this type to make it immutable and just set the properties from a constructor.)

Using this we can create a `Dictionary<Foo, List<Whatever>>` and look up a collection of...whatever, given an object that specifies these three values.

Now this will only work for finding values where all of the given values are exactly equal.  Hash based structures inherently don't work for finding all possible values within a given range.  In order to do that we'll need to store all of our data in a sorted data structure, find the first item above the beginning of our range, and then continue grabbing consecutive items until the item passes the end of our range.

To do this we'll start with a `BinarySearch` method that can find the index of the item equal to a given item, or the index of the next largest item:

```
public static int BinarySearch<T>(
    this  IList<T> collection, T item, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = collection.Count;
    while (startIndex <= endIndex)
    {
        int testIndex = startIndex + ((endIndex - startIndex) / 2);
        if (testIndex == collection.Count)
            return testIndex;
        int comparision = comparer.Compare(collection[testIndex], item);
        if (comparision > 0)
        {
            endIndex = testIndex - 1;
        }
        else if (comparision == 0)
        {
            return testIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            startIndex = testIndex + 1;
        }
    }
    return startIndex;
}
```

From this we can write a method to get all items within a sorted list that are in a give range:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetWithinRange<T>
    (this IList<T> collection, T start, T end,
    IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    int index = collection.BinarySearch(start, comparer);
    while (index < collection.Count &&
        comparer.Compare(collection[index], end) <= 0)
    {
        yield return collection[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

Now for an actual data structure.  Since you say that you only need to compare one of your three parameters by range, the other two can leverage a hash based data structure:

```
public class Vector : IEquatable<Vector> //TODO consider renaming
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Vector);
    }

    public bool Equals(Vector other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return Angle == other.Angle &&
            Width == other.Width;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { Angle, Width }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Using this we can now write our:

```
Dictionary<Vector, SortedList<double, List<Something>>>
```

However, trying to deal with this directly, and also dealing with constantly creating intermediate structures as needed, would be hard, so we're really best off creating a custom data structure to abstract this away:

```
public class FooDataStructure //TODO rename
{
    private Dictionary<Vector, SortedList<double, List<Something>>> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<Vector, SortedList<double, List<Something>>>();

    public void Add(Foo foo, Something something)
    {
        var vector = new Vector { Angle = foo.Angle, Width = foo.Width };
        SortedList<double, List<Something>> list;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(vector, out list))
        {
            list = new SortedList<double, List<Something>>();
            dictionary.Add(vector, list);
        }
        List<Something> somethings;
        if (!list.TryGetValue(foo.Height, out somethings))
        {
            somethings = new List<Something>();
            list.Add(foo.Height, somethings);
        }
        somethings.Add(something);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Something> Find(
        double angle, double width, double minHeight, double maxHeight)
    {
        var vector = new Vector { Angle = angle, Width = width };
        SortedList<double, List<Something>> list;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(vector, out list))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Something>();
        }
        return list.Keys.GetWithinRange(minHeight, maxHeight)
            .SelectMany(key => list[key]);
    }
}
```

Now this is of course not complete.  It doesn't have a `Remove` method, it doesn't have a `Find` method that doesn't require a range of heights, or any other operations that might be expected of a lookup, but you should be able to model most of them given this premise.

Comment: hi Servy. Thank you very much for your suggestion, which looks very good to me. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention one special case, where the property height could have all the values together (e.g. 100-200, 200-300, 300-400; but also 100-400). Do you see a solution where it is still possible with a hash code? (I'd love to use the hash code, because it's really fast). Thanks!

Comment: @casaout You can do it, but it makes life **much** harder

Comment: hi Servy. Thank you for your awesome & valuable help! What I could also do is stick with the first version and (in the case of all three properties for height) just get the values of these three hashes (as this is fixed) and merge it. What do you think?

Comment: @casaout If it's always a very small range, then sure, that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Tuple in a list

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: A `List` isn't going to give you very efficient searching speed; you end up needing to search through every single item in the collection to find it.  A `Tuple` is also not a very good idea for a structure like this; it is rather burdonsome on the user of the type to try to remember which item corresponds to each of the three values.  A custom type with meaningful names is almost certainly worth the effort.